# How to implement the jquery page transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I am developing phonegap application . I want to add native  slide page transition while switching the pages. I am not using jquery mobile. Instead of that I am using the bootstrap . But the problem is there is nothing for page transitions in the bootstrap. so is there any way in jquery or javascript using which it can be implemented in the application.I have searched a lot but all the example are only for the div transitions .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CSS library called Animate.css (http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). You can add animation classes to the pages & slide then in left & right. I had some time so made a working demo of how it will work -

**WORKING DEMO** - http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/FIzst

So basically I have created a page structure & on click on page links, I am assigning them the required class for the slide effect. This also handles next & previous page handling so if you move from 1st page to 2nd, the slide would be from right to left & if you go from 2nd to 1st the slide would be left to right.

**HTML Structure**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="3">Page 3</a></li>
</ul> 
<div class="container">
    <div class="page active" id="page-1" data-page="1">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
        <p>
            <a href="#"  class="page-link btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-page="2" role="button">Next &raquo;</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="page" id="page-2"  data-page="2">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
        <p>
            <a href="#"  class="page-link btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-page="1" role="button">&laquo; Prev</a>
            <a href="#"  class="page-link btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-page="3" role="button">Next &raquo;</a>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="page" id="page-3"  data-page="3">
        <h1>Page 3</h1>
        <p>
            <a href="#"  class="page-link btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-page="2" role="button">&laquo; Prev</a>
        </p>
    </div>

        </div> <!-- /container -->
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.page-link').click(function(){
     var goToPage = $(this).data('page');
     var nextPage = $('#page-' + goToPage);
     var currPage = $('.page.active');
     if(goToPage > currPage.data('page')) {
       currPage.addClass('animated slideOutLeft');
       nextPage.addClass('active animated slideInRight');
     } else if(goToPage < currPage.data('page')) {
       currPage.addClass('animated slideOutRight');
       nextPage.addClass('active animated slideInLeft');
     }
     currPage.removeClass('active animated slideInRight slideInLeft slideOutRight slideOutLeft');
  });
});
```